# How to add a dropdown menu in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-api

I need a way to add a Dropdown menu ( or similar solution ) to show the metrics for only one cpu ( cpu 1 or cpu 0 ). Is this possible?
The metric is node_cpu_seconds_total

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Create a custom variable named "cpu" with values 0 and 1 in ***Dashboard settings*** > ***Variables*** > ***New***

[image]

2. Create the graph panel using the cpu variable (use the ":pipe" suffix to enable the use of 0 and 1 options at the same time)

[image]

3. The CPU can be selected in the dropdown menu

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to show that metric for only one node too?

Comment: Check the syntax, maybe you wrote something wrong. You can select any label you want (instance, mode, etc) using the same strategy.

Comment: Do you have the "$instance" variable that I used in my example? I bet you not. Change to "localhost:9100" that exists in your case.